# FFmpeg with libwebp in centos

Tags: ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg with rpmfusion but not support webp!
Do you have any simple solution or we must compile it from source?
Is it possible to use Source RPMs and enable libwebp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg has built-in support for WebP decoding.

FFmpeg uses libwebp for WebP encoding, so you build must have `--enable-libwebp` to be able to encode WebP.

You can compile by adapting [FFmpeg Wiki: CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) and manually adding the WebP dependency.

Or the easy solution is to download an already compiled `ffmpeg` from [johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). See [FAQ](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for install instructions.